# T-SQL - Date rounding and normalization

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure that rounds a column with dates  in (yyyy:mm:dd hh:mM:ss) to the nearest 10 minute handle (yyyy:mm:dd hh:mM)

20100303 09:46:3000 ------> 20100303 09:50

but i want to chage it to round it off to the nearest 15 minute handle:

20100303 09:46:3000 ------>20100303 09:45

here is my code :

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SPNormalizeAddWhen]') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNormalizeAddWhen]

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPNormalizeAddWhen]
As
declare @colname nvarchar(20)
set @colname='Normalized Add_When'

if not exists (select * from syscolumns where id=object_id('Risk') and name=@colname)
    exec('alter table Risk add [' + @colname  + '] datetime')


declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @sql='update Risk set [' + @colname + ']=cast(DATEPART(yyyy,[add when]) as nvarchar(4)) + ''-'' + cast(DATEPART(mm,[add when]) as nvarchar(2)) + ''-'' + cast(DATEPART(dd,[add when]) as nvarchar(2)) + '' '' + cast(DATEPART(Hh,[add when]) as nvarchar(2)) + '':''  + cast(round(DATEPART(Mi,[add when]),-1) as nvarchar(2)) '
print @sql
exec(@sql)
GO
```

Comment: so essentially you want us to do your work for you? First, you should work out how 'your' stored procedure works. Then you should alter it accordingly,

Comment: dont understand how you are "doing" any work for me,i have written this code myself and it works perfectly fine:it rounds up the minute to the nearest 10 minute fine,i was trying ot round it to the nearest 15 minute and could not find anything useful,so was looking for pointers...

Comment: for others interested in actually giving useful suggestions here is what i am looking for:
select round(46,-1) = 50
select round(46,?)=45

its this line i need to change but with what:

cast(round(DATEPART(Mi,[add when]),-1) ---> replace -1 with what?

Answer (score 3):

To round a time to the nearest 15 minutes...

```
Select GetDate(), 
       DateAdd(Minute, 15 * Round(DateDiff(minute, 0, GetDate())/15.0, 0), 0)
```